# Python module Import error for one user but not the other

Tags: linux, redhat, python-2.6

This works:

```
root@host#/usr/bin/python26 script.py 
Success
```

This results in an error:

```
user@host$/usr/bin/python26 script.py

ImportError: No module named OpenSSL
```

The users have identical PYTHONPATHs.  Why does the 2nd user fail to import the module?

Comment: PYTHONPATH is a list of directory that is appended to the default search path. So, in order for PYTHONPATH to be relevant to the issue, the OpenSSL module would need to be in one of PYTHONPATH's included directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran chmod 755 on all directories in python path.

Non-root user was able to execute script after this.