# How to send data stored in a variable to HDFS in python

Tags: python, shell, hdfs, devops

Example:

```
data = "my first program"
```

How can I write the data of this variable in hdfs file using python?

I have tried using:

```
command = 'echo $data | hdfs dfs -put - /user/test/abc.txt'
os.system(command)`
```

Comment: If you have tried this please add the error message you got.

Comment: i'm not getting any error. but when i tried hdfs dfs -put - /user/test/abc.txt, it is showing a blank file abc.txt. that means 'echo $data' is not working properly

Comment: Use subprocess module to run a bash command from python

Comment: @NihalSangeeth 
can u give an example

Comment: Sure. check out the answer

Comment: the file is still blank.
basically the data variable has json data.

Comment: Obviously because `echo $data`  returns null. data is a python variable. How can you access it through a bash command. Check out the second method. That is the better practise.

Comment: in python it should be 

command = 'echo ' + data + '  | hdfs dfs -put - /user/test/abc.txt'

Answer (score 0):

Use subprocess module to run a bash command from python.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen("echo $data | hdfs dfs -put - /user/test/abc.txt", 
shell="TRUE" , stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
print(process.returncode)
```

But ideally use a native pythonhdfs connector. [Check out.](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/python-hdfs-interfaces/)

Here's a snippet from the documentation.

```
from pyarrow import HdfsClient
# Using libhdfs
hdfs = HdfsClient(host, port, username, driver='libhdfs') 
# Using libhdfs3
hdfs_alt = HdfsClient(host, port, username, driver='libhdfs3')
path = '/user/test/abc.txt'
with hdfs.open(path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)`
```

Comment: tried first solution but still getting a blank file 

while trying second solution , getting this error "Error: No module named pyarrow"

Comment: did that..
i tried sudo pip install pyarrow and it was completed successfully.
but after that also getting the same error

Comment: Which version of python? Are you using a virtualenv? If its python3 then use `pip3 install pyarrow`

Comment: it 2.7 version. it is not a virtual env

Comment: Ok go into your `python` shell and `import pyarrow`. Because you havent correctly installed pyarrow module

Comment: pyarrow is working from root but is not working from hadoop user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244850/python-module-import-error-for-one-user-but-not-the-other

Comment: so the second approach is not working in my case.
can u help me with some other method

Comment: You are not providing sufficient information. No error message. No hint as to why its not working. Please checkout Stack Overflow's guidelines to write a question.